# Entity Framework call best way to call a another api

Tags: entity-framework-6

Building an api around a db and as part of this we'll be calling another api and joining data in that api to the database for viewing but not storing the data in the current database.  My question is if this.
In my data model I have

```
public class server
{
   public Int32 ServerID {get;set;}
   public string ServerName {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

If I add api columns with to the server object

```
public string ServerMemory
```

That of course returns and invalid column name because this is data from the api that is not in the database table.
I see a few options

1. Create a view within the database structure which has some blank columns and reference that within my data model.
2. Create another object within my data model and then reference it using virtual using something like the method mentioned here: https://jeremiahflaga.github.io/2020/02/16/entity-framework-6-error-invalid-column-name-_id/
3. Create another object and a cast to cast the Server object to this other object.

Is there another simpler way to reference a foreign field within an object in a data model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this so anyone else who needs to add a column to a datamodel that does not exist in the database

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

then you can use this:

```
 [NotMapped]
 public virtual  string RoleDesc { get; set; }
```

Still curious if this is the best way.  I guess that really revolves around your goals.